# Rendering html within html output

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have a html script which produces a sankey diagram and want to embed this into the rshiny app, however, I cannot successfully input this without getting a Not Found error. I imagine it would be embedded within the iframe, so that it appears inside the tabPanel output respective to the sidebar.

My example implementation:

```
code = "<html>
  <head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['sankey']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'From');
  data.addColumn('string', 'To');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
  data.addRows([
    [ 'A', 'X', 5 ],
    [ 'A', 'Y', 7 ],
    [ 'A', 'Z', 6 ],
    [ 'B', 'X', 2 ],
    [ 'B', 'Y', 9 ],
    [ 'B', 'Z', 4 ]
  ]);
  
  // Sets chart options.
  var options = {
    width: 600,
  };
  
  // Instantiates and draws our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_basic'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id='sankey_basic' style='width: 900px; height: 300px;'></div>
  </body>
  </html>
  "


ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    id='navid',
    window_title = 'SomeTitle',
    theme=bslib::bs_theme(version= '3', bootswatch="flatly"),,
    tabPanel('Intro'),
    tabPabel('Input',
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 actionBttn('sankey', 'Sankey', color='success', style = 'bordered')
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 tabPanel('Tab1', htmlOutput("map"))
               )
             ))
  
  )
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(id="navid",collapsible = TRUE,
             position = "static-top",
             fluid = TRUE,
             windowTitle = "some title",
             theme=bslib::bs_theme(version= '3', bootswatch="flatly"),
             "some title",
             tabPanel("Intro",
                      fluidPage( 
                        titlePanel(h3("Introduction")),
                          fluid = TRUE)
                      ),
             tabPanel('Input',
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          actionBttn('sankey', 'Sankey', color='success', style = 'bordered')
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabPanel('Tab1', htmlOutput("map"))
                        )
                      ))))


server <- function(input,output){
  output$map <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(seamless="seamless", 
                src= HTML(code),
                width=800, 
                height=800)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a **www** subfolder in your app folder, and in this subfolder  include this file ***sankey.js***:

```js
google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["sankey"] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn("string", "From");
  data.addColumn("string", "To");
  data.addColumn("number", "Weight");
  data.addRows([
    ["A", "X", 5],
    ["A", "Y", 7],
    ["A", "Z", 6],
    ["B", "X", 2],
    ["B", "Y", 9],
    ["B", "Z", 4]
  ]);

  // Sets chart options.
  var options = {
    width: 600
  };

  // Instantiates and draws our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(
    document.getElementById("sankey_basic")
  );
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

The chart will appear in the `div` element of your app with id `sankey_basic`. Here is a minimal UI:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"),
    tags$script(src = "sankey.js")
  ),
  tags$div(
    id = "sankey_basic", 
    style = "width: 900px; height: 300px"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get the image to show whilst following your apprach